# What is the purpose of the s==NULL case for mbrtowc?

Tags: c, standards, multibyte, language-lawyer

`mbrtowc` is specified to handle a `NULL` pointer for the `s` (multibyte character pointer) argument as follows:

> If s is a null pointer, the mbrtowc() function shall be equivalent to the call:
>
> ```
> mbrtowc(NULL, "", 1, ps)
> ```
>
> In this case, the values of the arguments pwc and n are ignored.

As far as I can tell, this usage is largely useless. If `ps` is not storing any partially-converted character, the call will simply return 0 with no side effects. If `ps` is storing a partially-converted character, then since `'\0'` is not valid as the next byte in a multibyte sequence (`'\0'` can only be a string terminator), the call will return `(size_t)-1` with `errno==EILSEQ`. and leave `ps` in an undefined state.

The intended usage seems to have been to reset the state variable, particularly when `NULL` is passed for `ps` and the internal state has been used, analogous to `mbtowc`'s behavior with stateful encodings, but this is *not specified anywhere* as far as I can tell, and it conflicts with the semantics for `mbrtowc`'s storage of partially-converted characters (if `mbrtowc` were to reset state when encountering a 0 byte after a potentially-valid initial subsequence, it would be unable to detect this dangerous invalid sequence).

If `mbrtowc` were specified to reset the state variable only when `s` is `NULL`, but not when it points to a 0 byte, a desirable state-reset behavior would be possible, but such behavior would violate the standard as written. Is this a defect in the standard? As far as I can tell, there is absolutely no way to reset the internal state (used when `ps` is `NULL`) once an illegal sequence has been encountered, and thus no correct program can use `mbrtowc` with `ps==NULL`.

Comment: Maybe a case of design-by-committee? i.e: someone wanted to make sure that passing NULL for each of `pwc`, `s`, and `ps` was specified.

Answer (score 5):

Since a '\0' byte must convert to a null wide character regardless of shift state (5.2.1.2 Multibyte characters), and the `mbrtowc()` function is specified to reset the shift state when it converts to a wide null character (7.24.6.3.2/3 The mbrtowc function), calling `mbrtowc( NULL, "", 1, ps)` will reset the shift state stored in the `mbstate_t` pointed to by `ps`.  And if `mbrtowc( NULL, "", 1, NULL)` is called to use the library's internal `mbstate_t` object, it will be reset to an initial state.  See the end of the answer for cites of the relevant bits of the standard.

I'm by no means particularly experienced with the C standard multibyte conversion functions (my experience with this kind of thing has been using the Win32 APIs for conversion).

If `mbrtowc()` processes a 'incomplete char' that's cut short by a 0 byte, it should return `(size_t)(-1)` to indicate an invalid multibyte char (and thus detect the dangerous situation you describe).  In that case the conversion/shift state is unspecified (and I think you're basically hosed for that string). The multibyte 'sequence' that a conversion was attempted on but contains a `'\0'` is invalid and ever will be valid with subsequent data.  If the `'\0`' wasn't intended to be part of the converted sequence, then it shouldn't have been included in the count of bytes available for processing.

If you're in a situation where you might get additional, subsequent bytes for a partial multibyte char (say from a network stream), the `n` you passed for the partial multibyte char shouldn't include a 0 byte, so you'll get a `(size_t)(-2)` returned. In this case, if you pass a `'\0'` while in the middle of the partial conversion, you'll lose the fact that there's an error and as a side-effect reset the `mbstate_t` state in use (whether it's your own or the internal one being used because you passed in a NULL pointer for `ps`).  I think I'm essentailly restating your question here.

However I think it is possible to detect and handle this situation, but unfortunately it requires keeping track of some state yourself:

```
#define MB_ERROR    ((size_t)(-1))
#define MB_PARTIAL  ((size_t)(-2))

// function to get a stream of multibyte characters from somewhere
int get_next(void);

int bar(void)
{
    char c;
    wchar_t wc;
    mbstate_t state = {0};

    int in_partial_convert = 0;

    while ((c = get_next()) != EOF)
    {
        size_t result = mbrtowc( &wc, &c, 1, &state);

        switch (result) {
        case MB_ERROR:
            // this multibyte char is invalid
            return -1;
        case MB_PARTIAL:
            // do nothing yet, we need more data
            // but remember that we're in this state
            in_partial_convert = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            // output the competed wide char
            in_partial_convert = 0;     // no longer in the middle of a conversion
            putwchar(wc);
            break;
        case 0:
            if (in_partial_convert) {
                // this 'last' multibyte char was mal-formed
                // return an error condidtion
                return -1;
            }
            // end of the multibyte string
            // we'll handle similar to EOF
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe not an ideal situation, but I think it shows it's not completely broken so as to be impossible to use.

---

Standards citations:

5.2.1.2 Multibyte characters

> - A multibyte character set may have a state-dependent encoding, wherein
>     each sequence of multibyte characters
>     begins in an initial shift state and
>     enters other locale-specific shift
>     states when specific multibyte
>     characters are encountered in the
>     sequence. While in the initial shift
>     state, all single-byte characters
>     retain their usual interpretation and
>     do not alter the shift state. The
>     interpretation for subsequent bytes in
>     the sequence is a function of the
>     current shift state.
> - A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character
>     independent of shift state.
> - A byte with all bits zero shall not occur in the second or subsequent
>     bytes of a multibyte character.

7.24.6.3.2/3 The mbrtowc function

> If the corresponding wide character is
>   the null wide character, the resulting
>   state described is the initial
>   conversion state

Comment: The consensus seems to be that `mbrtowc` *does* store the state for partially converted characters. This is based on text "and all n bytes have been processed" in the standard. All known implementations behave this way except ancient versions of `libutf8`, and the `libutf8` documentation has an explanation of why the author was convinces that his original implementation was wrong and changed it. And this behavior is incompatible with `'\0'` unconditionally resetting state...

Comment: Note that non-initial "shift state" and being in the middle of an incomplete character are two completely different things. I agree that the standard requires `'\0'` to be interpreted as the null wide character regardless of shift state, but even if it required it to be interpreted as the null wide-character after an incomplete character, no sane implementation would follow that behavior since it would create major security issues and violate Unicode requirements for processing UTF-8 safely.

Comment: @R.: you're completely right about my misstatements about restarting a partial conversion.  I've updated the answer to remove my mistakes (I hope).  I've also updated it to give an example of how I think an errant `'\0'` character being processed while a partial conversion is 'in progress' can be detected and handled. It's not the cleanest thing I've seen, but it's also not nearly the ugliest workaround I've written.  Let me know if I'm still missing something (clearly, this isn't exactly an expertise of mine - I'm on the verge of deleting the answer altogether).

Comment: If nothing else, your "workaround" code for a `mbrtowc` function that resets state on encountering a 0 byte mid-character is worth leaving here. Do you know of any implementations where this is necessary?

Comment: My reading of the standard is that when `mbrtowc()` is passed a `'\0'` byte as the byte to process, it needs to reset the state. What I posted would just be a way for the caller to detect that in the middle of a partial conversion. I don't really know about the details of implementations. My experience with multibyte conversion is using the Win32 APIs, not the standard lib, to convert a string as a whole, therefore I never needed to deal with conversion state. And for me the conversion either worked or it didn't - I didn't have to try and determine where or why the conversion failed.

Comment: @Michael: The closest I can find in the standard is the requirement that a 0 byte be interpreted as the null wide character regardless of shift state. The only way this would apply is if the initial bytes of a multibyte character are deemed to constitute a "shift state" by the standard. But considering partial characters as shift states seems to conflict with `mbtowc` semantics, or at least the usual implementations, which do not process partial characters.

Comment: @R.: "The only way this would apply is if the initial bytes of a multibyte character are deemed to constitute a 'shift state' by the standard." They are.

Comment: @Daniel: Where do you get that?

Comment: @R.: I get that from 5.2.1.2: "A multibyte character set may have a state-dependent encoding, wherein each sequence of multibyte characters begins in an initial shift state and enters other locale-specific shift states when specific multibyte characters are encountered in the sequence.  While in the initial shift state, all single-byte characters retain their usual interpretation and do not alter the shift state. The interpretation for subsequent bytes in the sequence is a function of the current shift state."

Comment: @R. - I've added a paragraph to the start of the answer text that I believe shows why the shift state object (internal or caller provided) must be reset to an initial state when `mbrtowc()` is called with a source string pointing to a `'\0'` byte. The relevant bits from the standard are quoted at the end (footnotes if you will).

Comment: In the 5.2.1.2 citation, I take the third bullet point as indicating that encountering a zero byte after a partial character must be interpreted as an illegal sequence (with the resulting undefined state for the `mbstate_t` object). Bullet 2 is only about shift states, not partial characters.

Comment: @R. - I read the bullet points in 5.2.1.2 as meaning that a '\0' byte occurring in a multibyte stream can be unambiguously considered a null char. The described behavior of `mbrtowc()` when passed an empty source string seems certainly intended to reset the `mbstate_t` object regardless of the current state, and I think 5.2.1.2 gives it the ability to do so in a well-defined way.  Then again, that's my reading - I'm certainly not on the standards committee, and I admittedly don't have much experience with these standard functions.

Answer (score 1):

In 5.2.1.2, Multibyte characters, the C Standard states:

> A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character independent of shift
>   state.  Such a byte shall not occur as part of any other multibyte character.

The Standard seems to differentiate between shift state and conversion state, as, for example, 7.24.6 mentions:

> The conversion state described by the pointed-to object is altered as needed to track the shift state, *and the position within a multibyte character*, for the associated multibyte character sequence.

(emphasis added by me). However, I think that the intent is to interpret a byte with all zero bits as the null character regardless of the mbstate_t value, which encodes the entire conversion state, particularly as "Such a byte shall not occur as part of any other multibyte character" implies that the null byte **cannot** occur within a multibyte character. If a null byte *does* occur in errant input where the second, third, etc. byte of a multibyte character should be, then I interpret the Standard as saying that the partial multibyte character at the EOF is silently ignored.

My reading of 7.24.6.3.2, The `mbrtowc` function, for the case when `s` is `NULL` is thus: the next 1 byte completes the null wide character, the return value of `mbrtowc` is 0, and the resulting state is the initial conversion state because:

> If the corresponding wide character is the null wide character, the resulting state described is the initial conversion state.

By passing `NULL` for both `s` and `ps`, the internal mbstate_t of `mbrtowc` is reset to the initial state.

Comment: Again this interpretation depends on considering proper multibyte characters to be comprised of a shift state followed by a character byte. I have never seen an implementation that does so for UTF-8. (If it did, then `mbtowc` would have to be stateful and accept byte-at-a-time decoding, and I've never seen an implementation that allows such.) In the absence of evidence to the contrary, I'm inclined to believe that the standard allows both *shift states* and characters of length greater than one byte in the *default shift state* as long as they don't begin with a basic character set byte.

Comment: Your last comment makes no sense. `mbsrtowcs` operates on whole strings, whereas `mbrtowc` *can* and *does* support byte-at-a-time decoding (returning -2 but keeping the partial character stored in its `mbstate_t` object). On the other hand, all implementations of `mbtowc` (note the missing `r`) I've used return `-1` on partial UTF-8 characters. I have no idea how this is intended to work with legacy multibyte character encodings (Shift_JIS etc.).

Comment: @R.: Sorry. I wasn't thinking clearly. You are correct that when `mbrtowc` returns -2, it has processed each of the *n* bytes and updated the mbstate_t appropriately. Also, the end effect is the same as if `mbrtowc` were called *n* times, once for each byte (byte-at-a-time decoding).

Comment: @R.: That `mbtowc` returns -1 on the partial UTF-8 encoding of a codepoint is correct. When `mbtowc` returns -1, then the caller knows that a full wide char could not be decoded, so the caller needs to retrieve more data and re-call `mbtowc` with the same `s`, but a higher `n`.

Comment: @R..: ... (`n` should be greater than or equal to `MB_CUR_MAX` or else `mbtowc` could return -1 again).

Comment: @R..: I don't understand your first comment. By "multibyte character", the Standard means a "sequence of one or more bytes representing a member of the extended character set of either the source or the execution environment". When using UTF-8, for example, multibyte characters are between 1 and 4 bytes long.

Comment: By "proper multibyte character" I simply mean a multibyte character consisting of more than one byte. I see no language in the standard that equates "partial characters" (e.g. the `c3` byte in UTF-8) with "shift states" (which I, and apparently many other people, take to mean bytes like the `0e` and `0f` in ISO-2022).

Comment: @R..: Actually, I should be more precise and say "octet". UTF-8 encodes codepoints in 1 to 4 octets.

Comment: Note that 7.24.1 defines `mbstate_t` as "an object type other than an array type that can hold the conversion state information necessary to convert between sequences of multibyte characters and wide characters". The word "shift state" is not used which makes me think that "conversion state information" potentially includes something other than a "shift state", which could only conceivably be a partially-decoded initial subsequence of a multibyte character that is not considered a "shift state" by the implementation.

Comment: @R..: By "shift state", the Standard means the conversion state information. In 5.2.1.2, which I also quoted in a comment to Michael's answer, the Standard has "A multibyte character set may have a *state-dependent encoding*, wherein each sequence of multibyte characters begins in an *initial shift state* and enters other locale-specific *shift states* when specific multibyte characters are encountered in the sequence". So, while the definition of `mbstate_t` does not mention "shift state", I read 5.2.1.2 as implicitly defining *shift state* to mean all of the conversion state information.

Comment: @R..: It's really confusing because "shift state" also means something different. For instance, some people write that UTF-8 does not use "shift state", which is a correct statement according to one meaning of "shift state", but not according to the C Standard's definition, I think.

Comment: @R..: Basically, my argument is that "shift state" exactly means "conversion state" because when the standard talks about "state-dependent encodings", it only mentions "shift state".

Comment: Your reasoning is circular. Only state-dependent encodings have "shift states"; this is almost tautological. But UTF-8 is clearly not state-dependent both in the sense of ordinary language and the sense of `mbtowc` (without the `r`). `mbrtowc` was added to the language after `mbtowc`, and it seems to me rather odd that the addition of a new interface would change the statefulness (or lack thereof) that `mbtowc` reports for UTF-8.

Comment: @R..: If you are decoding a UTF-8-encoded multibyte string to a wide string, and the first call to `mbrtowc` has `n` equal to 1 and `s` equal to `"\xC2\x...`, then the decoding at the second byte is not in the initial conversion state. That to me is "state-dependent". `mbtowc` does not accept the mbstate_t object, which encodes the shift state or conversion state information, because it's all or nothing; either `mbtowc` can decode a multibyte character to a wide char or it can't. If it can't, then `mbtowc` returns -1 and the caller knows to retry with a higher `n`.

Comment: The phrase "state-dependent encoding" is used in the specification of `mbtowc`: `mbtowc(0,0,0)` returns 0 if and only if character encodings do not have a state-dependent encoding. I don't see how it would make sense for this function to return 1 for UTF-8, especially if the implementation were written before `mbrtowc` was added to the language. As for `mbrtowc`, it has a *decoding state*, but that does not imply that the encoding of characters is stateful.

Comment: @R..: I am convinced that you are right about "'conversion state information' potentially [including] something other than a 'shift state'". I read through all mentions of "state-dependent" in the Standard and also read, in 7.24.6, that "The conversion state described by the pointed-to object is altered as needed to track the shift state, and the position within a multibyte character, for the associated multibyte character sequence." Granted I only have access to the final draft of ISO/IEC 9899:TC2, but I think that this wording was not changed in the published standard.

Comment: @R..: It almost seems that to fix this issue, the Standard should say "A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character independent of **conversion** state." I believe, however, that the intent of passing `NULL` for `s` is to reset the internal state (or passed mbstate_t if `ps` is not `NULL`).

Comment: Silently ignoring a partial multibyte character terminated with a zero byte would be a catastrophic pandora's box of vulnerabilities. The standard is unambiguous that if `mbrtowc` sees them together (e.g. `c3 00` with length >=2) this is not a valid character and `mbrtowc` must return -1. I agree it's not entirely clear what is supposed to happen in the case of two separate calls with single bytes passed each time, but I don't see any language that mandates your interpretation, and it's clearly harmful to security.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why you want to "fix the issue" by making the interface insecure (failing to detect dangerous erroneous data) and/or harder to use. What is the issue anyway? That there may be no way to reset the internal state once it gets in an invalid state? There are two easy fixes to this: either (1) deprecate use of the internal state, or (2) specify that if `s` is a NULL pointer, the internal `mbstate_t` object is reset (instead of specifying the NULL pointer case in terms of another call that *does not necessarily* have that behavior).

Comment: @R..: Could you clarify why silently ignoring a partial multibyte character at the end is insecure? Also, what text from the Standard says that a null byte terminating a partial multibyte character should be treated like an invalid multibyte char?

Comment: Two non-identical byte strings should never convert to the same wide character string. This is a fundamental property of UTF-8. Imagine something like `"..\xc2"` getting decoded to `L".."`. Or even just a string that was confirmed (as a byte string) to be non-empty later getting decoded to an empty wide string. These nasty behaviors are possible with some ugly legacy multibyte encodings (anything ISO-2022-based for example), which are generally **not supported** on Unix systems because they lead to security problems.

Comment: As for "what text from the standard...", by 5.2.1.2 bullet point 3, it can't be a valid character. If the prefix were considered a *shift state*, rather than a partial character, then it could be discarded as a redundant shift before the terminating null, but I specifically said "partial multibyte character" rather than "shift prefix". For UTF-8 support that conforms to Unicode, you cannot treat prefixes as shift states because encountering an incomplete or invalid sequence must be reported as an error (preferable) or via a replacement character.

Comment: And note that the replacement character approach that Unicode allows is *not possible* with the `mbrtowc` API in this situation. This is because on encountering `c3 00` would have to interpret `c3` as a 1-byte multibyte character resulting in the replacement character, since it cannot (by the C standard) consider `00` to be part of the multibyte character. But then decoding any UTF-8 character beginning with `c3` would be impossible.